# Php-javascript code working only once

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I have simple code that inserts values to database without page refresh using javascript.
The problem is that when I use "onchange" atrribute in method to call the function the code works fine and value is inserted but when i remove "onchange"  form and use a Button "onclick" attribute to call same method it works on once and then stops working.

The code of my **comment.html** file is

```
 <html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="GET">
<input type="text" name="q">
<button method="GET" onclick="showUser(q.value)">Submit</button>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the code of my **getuser.php** file is:

```
  <?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','login');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql2= "INSERT INTO `users` ( `FirstName`) VALUES( '{$_GET['q']}') "; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
while($row = $result)
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You should keep your `mysqli` connection on a separate secure page, using `new mysqli(/*args*/)`, and use the Object Oriented PHP style. It makes life easier.

Comment: If you put an `alert` in `showUser()` does it fire?

Comment: Yes alert is getting fired

Comment: Does `str == ''`? If your input is empty or the number 0, your function returns before executing AJAX.

Comment: Why are people so insisting on using both a `form` _and_ `ajax` at the same time?

Comment: @PHPglue if I alert before return it works so return would also be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lavneet is in right direction, but does not solve the problem.

If you *insist* of that setup you must return `false` in the `onclick` :

```
<button onclick="showUser(q.value);return false;">Submit</button>
```

by that, the form is not re-submitted after `showUser()`.

Answer (score 2):

code is correct except the button that you've created.

use: `<input type="button" onclick="showUser(q.value)" value="Submit">`

instead of: `<button method="GET" onclick="showUser(q.value)">Submit</button>`

What you've done is actually submitting the form. So, the onclick event is being overridden.

Comment: No, even if you remove method="GET" it is the same. You have to remove  <form> ..</form>

Comment: Its working but dont know why now nothing is being appended in URL

Comment: On removing the method="GET" will not solve the problem. You can even try that thing. The <form> thinks <button> as a submit parameter rather than a simple button.

Comment: Prince: Nothing is being appended in URL because you're calling the PHP file through Ajax. Actually, it is being appended but that's not visible to you.. ;)